# Find all files pattern with total size

Tags: linux, shell

In order to find all logs files with a pattern from all subdirectories I used the command :

```
du -csh *log.2017*
```

But this command does not search in subdirectories. Is there any way to get the total size of all files with a pattern from all subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```sh
find . -name *log.2017* | xargs du -csh
```

Comment: You need to surround your `*log.2017*` with double quotes.

Comment: @Cristian Bidea Thank You for the comment. However, this script gives the same result as `du -csh`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks but gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name *log.2017* -type f -exec stat -c "%s" {} \; | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use find command

```
find /path -type f -name "*log.2017*" -exec stat -c "%s" {} \; | bc
```

It will do the search recursively.

Comment: Where does this give the total size?

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ this script keeps listing sizes of all files, sorry didn't work for me.